# adding definitions to namespace alias

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it possible to add something to a namespace alias?
Or how can I achieve the following:

```
using KdTree = ExternalLibrary::Special::KdTree;

namespace KdTree{
    class MySpezial {};
};
```

That does not work, but the following works:

```
using KdTree = ExternalLibrary::Special::KdTree;

namespace ExternalLibrary{ namespace Special { namespace KdTree{
    class MySpezial {};
}}};
```

Is the first method just prohibited by the standart?

Answer (score 3):

The first example is currently not allowed and probably won't be in C++1Z either, but note that a [recent proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4026.html) is allowing

```
namespace ExternalLibrary::Special::KdTree {
    class MySpezial {};
}
```

This is already [implemented in Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab17c0bc93638616).